# WSO2 API 1.8.0: deployment over cluster does not work

Tags: api, deployment, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a clustered enviroment over 2 servers with WSO2 API Manager. I create a copy of an existing service and publish this.

Calling this service via SoapUI, one time it works, the other time does not.

```
STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /gm/services/aanvraag/MKE1
```

I have a registry-based-sync configured, the master node:

```
<DeploymentSynchronizer>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <AutoCommit>true</AutoCommit>
    <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
</DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

the slave node

```
<DeploymentSynchronizer>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <AutoCommit>false</AutoCommit>
    <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
</DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

This is my log of wso2carbon.log

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:40,712]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.internal.ApplicationManagementServiceComponent} -  Identity ApplicationManagementComponent bundle is activated {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.internal.ApplicationManagementServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:40,774]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.internal.IdPManagementServiceComponent} -  Identity Application Management Database initialization not attempted since 'setup' variable was not provided during startup {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.internal.IdPManagementServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:41,235]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.security.internal.SecurityMgtServiceComponent} -  POX Security Disabled {org.wso2.carbon.security.internal.SecurityMgtServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:41,364]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} -  Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:41,397]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} -  Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:41,398]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} -  Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:41,401]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} -  Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:41,421]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Cluster domain: api.tac.ibridge.wso2.carbon.domain {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:41,422]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Using multicast based membership management scheme {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:48,881]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Hazelcast initialized in 7456ms {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:48,890]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Local member: [69047182-e689-493e-baa0-f0c10f93b75c] - Host:172.26.4.167, Remote Host:null, Port: 4000, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, Domain: api.tac.ibridge.wso2.carbon.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:49,495]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Cluster initialization completed {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:49,609]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.service.impl.TaskServiceImpl} -  Task service starting in CLUSTERED mode... {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.service.impl.TaskServiceImpl}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:49,628]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent} -  Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:52,377]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Received replayed message: a1b9c70f-b66e-4996-9f74-a1c7c544a957 {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:52,378]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.SynchronizeRepositoryRequest} -  Received [SynchronizeRepositoryRequest{tenantId=-1234, tenantDomain='carbon.super', messageId=a1b9c70f-b66e-4996-9f74-a1c7c544a957}]  {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.SynchronizeRepositoryRequest}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:52,378]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.SynchronizeRepositoryRequest} -  Updating repo update required parameter {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.SynchronizeRepositoryRequest}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:53,054]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://nxt-tac-app02.nl.rsg:9443/carbon/ {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:53,054]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  API Publisher Default Context : http://nxt-tac-app02.nl.rsg:9763/publisher {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:53,055]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  API Store Default Context : http://nxt-tac-app02.nl.rsg:9763/store {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:53,224]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent} -  Setting default carbon host for thrift key management service: nxt-tac-app02.nl.rsg {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:49:53,239]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent} -  Started thrift key mgt service at port:10397 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:50:21,380]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /gm/services/aanvraag/MKE1 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-05-12 14:50:22,885]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /gm/services/aanvraag/MKE1 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this error.

If you created a load balanced gateway, point the server URL in all publisher, store and keymanager products to the manager node of the gateway. The manager node is the only one that can commit to the Deployment Synchronizer.

When it was ocurring this erro my configuration on api-manager was:

```
                <Environment type="hybrid">
                    <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
        <!--
                    Server URL of the API gateway.
                    <ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL>
            -->
                    <ServerURL>https://gateway.server-wso2/services/</ServerURL>

        <!--
                    Admin username for the API gateway.
            -->
                    <Username>admin</Username>
        <!--
                    Admin password for the API gateway.
            -->
                    <Password>admin</Password>
        <!--
                    Endpoint URLs for the APIs hosted in this API gateway.
                    <GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
            -->
                    <GatewayEndpoint>http://gateway.server-wso2:8280,https://gateway.server-wso2:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
            </Environment>
```

Now the working structure has:

```
                <Environment type="hybrid">
                    <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
        <!--
                    Server URL of the API gateway.
                    <ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL>
            -->
                    <ServerURL>https://mgt.gateway.server-wso2/services/</ServerURL>

        <!--
                    Admin username for the API gateway.
            -->
                    <Username>admin</Username>
        <!--
                    Admin password for the API gateway.
            -->
                    <Password>admin</Password>
        <!--
                    Endpoint URLs for the APIs hosted in this API gateway.
                    <GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
            -->
                    <GatewayEndpoint>http://gateway.server-wso2:8280,https://gateway.server-wso2:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
            </Environment>
```

Note that the gateway endpoints dont change, because it´s from there that the final user will access the API.

Hope it helps.

:)

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I switched over to SVN based deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally when an API is deployed the gateway manager pushes it to gateway workers using depsyc.
so this is most probably related to depsync, you get this error when the API was not synced between gateway workers and manager.
Check your depsync settings, check svn.

You can check if the artifacts are synced in gateway workers by looking in folder 
repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs-default/apis

As a workaround you can delete /repository/deplyment/server on both gateway worker nodes and restart them. This will resolve any svn conflicts if there is any.